# how to capture waxsim stdout&stderr

Tags: iphone, macos, bash, ios-simulator, pipe

this is iPhone development on MacOS question, 
I am using 'waxsim' to start my iphone app on simulator.
like this:

```
/usr/local/bin/waxsim /Users/me/Desktop/app/build/Release-iphonesimulator/app.app
```

Inside my app I use printf(), and I cat see the printf messages printed in console.

But I cannot get them into the file or filter with grep! I try everything that normally works:

```
cmd | grep "x"
```

all messages are printed but not through the grep

```
cmd > myfile
```

all messages still go to console, nothing to the file

```
cmd &> myfile
```

This command does not print anything to console! But myfile only contains this:

```
Launching '/Users/me/Desktop/app/build/Release-iphonesimulator/app.app' on'Simulator - iOS 6.0'
```

but not the actual messages printed with printf

```
cmd 2>&1 > myfile
```

with this one just everything goes to console, nothing to the file.

I think waxsim does some tricks with pipes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cmd &> myfile` should work (or equivalently, `cmd > myfile 2>&1`, the order matters).

Chances are that the problem is that your messages get buffered, though. This is standard behavior when stdout isn't a terminal. If you shut down the simulator completely before looking at the file, are the messages there?

If so, try `script -q /dev/null yourcommand` (not sure about the OS X syntax of `script`. On Linux it would be `script -c "your command" /dev/null`).

Comment: Thank you that other guy! Killing simulator did not work, but making stdout unbuffered worked!
     `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);`